# R- sqldf -need explicit units for numeric conversion

Tags: r, sqldf

I need to join 2 tables using a Date field

```
> class(pagos$pseudo_1mes)
[1] "Date"
>  class(pseudo_meses$pseudo_1mes)
[1] "Date"
```

My code is:

```
library(sqldf)

pagos<-sqldf("select a.*, b.mes_atras from pagos a 
        left join pseudo_meses b
      on a.pseudo_1mes=b.pseudo_1mes")
```

And I get the following error and no result:

> Error in asfn(rs[[i]]) : need explicit units for numeric conversion

How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: Please provide reproducible code and data in your questions.

Comment: Also note that this produces the correct result for me and does not give an error: `library(sqldf); DF1 <- DF2 <- data.frame(d = Sys.Date()); sqldf("select * from DF1 left join DF2 on DF1.d = DF2.d")`

Answer (score 10):

One of my variables had class = 'difftime' instead of regular numeric because I subtracted dates. SQLDF does not work with the difftime class. What happened for me was that I had a data.table, subtracted some dates, and ended up with a difftime variable type. I converted to it to data.frame and when I did the subtraction again it was numeric.

Comment: I also used `difftime` on the affected dataset, there must be something to that

Comment: Same problem for me.  I had one difftime column in my dataframe.  The error went away after coercing it to numeric.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem. My solution is to add (method = "name__class") to the end of the command, such as:

```
sqldf("select * from pagos", method = "name__class")
```

However, it seem the format of date variable will be changed, albeit the date variable can be updated later. I think this is still a useful solution, since my purpose is to get sqldf work to solve a complex task while update a column is relatively much easier.

Comment: Excellent solution. Solved my problem (similar problem with the smbinning package). Thank you!

Comment: @Young: it works fine, thank you for your answer. How do we convert the date back to its original format?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message. I don't know the cause of the message, but giving **explicit units** in the sql query solved the problem for me.

Use:

```
sqldf("select x, y, z from pagos")
```

Don't use:

```
sqldf("select * from pagos")
```

Comment: I got `Error in asfn(rs[[i]]) : need explicit units for numeric conversion
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion` even with explicit column names

Comment: @peter so weird I tried many things but simply listing the columns in the select statement makes it work

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, then I found a variable in my dataset was not numerical. So I converted that variable to numerical (as.numeric()). Then it worked.

Comment: This seemed to take of the problem for me. It was the only change I made and the error went away.