# Issue in running sqldf command for comparing integers

Tags: mysql, r, sqldf

I am working on simple data like below:

```
teacher student
  12      409
  43      403
  12      415
  12      409
  67      311
  19      201
```

I am trying to retrieve the entries where *teacher = 12* and *student = 409*. I am using the following command:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT * 
      FROM df
      WHERE teacher == 12 and student == 409')
```

I know it is a basic command, but when I run it, I get the following error message:

```
Error in asfn(rs[[i]]) : need explicit units for numeric conversion
```

I get the same error, even when I run:

```
# Without the and condition
sqldf('SELECT * 
      FROM df
      WHERE teacher == 12')
```

or when I run this

```
# Single equal sign
sqldf('SELECT * 
      FROM df
      WHERE teacher = 12')
```

Please note that in my current dataset `df$teacher` and `df$student` are both integers. I want to understand why am I getting this error. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

My desired output is:

```
teacher   student
  12        409
  12        409
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you test on the data in my post

Comment: Relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025849/r-sqldf-need-explicit-units-for-numeric-conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need single `=`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT * 
      FROM df
      WHERE teacher = 12 and student = 409')
```

-output

```
 teacher student
1      12     409
2      12     409
```

---

With the OP's original data, that didn't fix, so, we may use the `method` argument`

```
sqldf('SELECT * 
      FROM df
      WHERE teacher = 12 and student = 409', method = 'name__class')
```

According to the `?sqldf`, the `"name__class"` is used with `Date` class as an example.  As the OP's original data is not shared, it is still not sure why it worked

> method = "name__class" which means that columns names that end in __class with two underscores where class is an R class (such as Date) are converted to that class and the __class portion is removed from the column name.`

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(teacher = c(12L, 43L, 12L, 12L, 67L, 19L), student = c(409L, 
403L, 415L, 409L, 311L, 201L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still get the same error even with a single ```=``` sign.

Comment: this is it

```Error in asfn(rs[[i]]) : need explicit units for numeric conversion```

Comment: @Sandy, I couldn't reproudce your error though

Comment: @Sandy I also tested by changing the class of the columns from `integer` to `numeric`.  it still works for me though.  Can you show `packageVersion('sqldf')`.  I used `0.4.11`

Comment: It is running on the sample data. But unfortunately, not on my original data with ```dim = 15994 * 34```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233258/discussion-between-sandy-and-akrun).

Comment: @Sandy It may be that your columns have precision i.e. it may be exactly 409 i..e `409.00000013` etc